# how to convert 1 digit, 2 digit, 3 digit, 4 digit number to '%H%M'?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using Fedex Dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/manishtripathi86/fedex-data). There is a column by the name of `Actual_Shipment_Time` which contains numbers from single digit to four digits which I'm trying to convert to time.

For example

- 5 needs to be 00:05,
- 23 needs to be 00:23
- 345 needs to be 03:45
- 2145 needs to be 21:45

Even 12 hours format is also acceptable.

When I run this code

```
df['Actual_Shipment_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual_Shipment_Time'], format = '%H%M').dt.strftime('%H%M')
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: time data '9' does not match format '%H%M' (match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `zfill` the column to 4 numbers

```py
df['Actual_Shipment_Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Actual_Shipment_Time']
                                             .astype(str)
                                             .str.zfill(4), format='%H%M')
                              .dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

```
print(df)

  Actual_Shipment_Time
0                00:05
1                00:23
2                03:45
3                21:45
```

There is no such time as `24:00`, so Pandas gives following error

```
$ pd.to_datetime('2400', format='%H%M')

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

To overcome it, we can use `errors='coerce'`

```
df['Actual_Shipment_Time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Actual_Shipment_Time']
                                             .fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)  # fill nan value by 0 and convert column to int then to string
                                             .str.zfill(4), format='%H%M', errors='coerce')
                              .dt.strftime('%H:%M')
                              .fillna('00:00')) # fill nat value by 00:00, nat is from 24:00
```

Comment: if you convert to string anyway, why take the datetime detour instead of just inserting the colon ?

Comment: @FObersteiner I just point how OP can use `pd.to_datetime` with this kind of data. Use datetime or finally convert to string again is OP's business.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh thank you. It worked on two columns but still not working on one. I get this error when i run your code.  **ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0**

Comment: @IbadUllah I don't understand *It worked on two columns but still not working on one*, which column gives you the error? The `Actual_Shipment_Time` column?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh There were three columns of that format(single digit to four) in my dataset. I ran your code on three columns, two of those are converted to *%H%M* but one of the column is giving this error *ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0*. is it because this column contain 0 value ?

Comment: @IbadUllah Not sure, I'm downloading the dataset to test, what are those three columns?